# How to use pip in Windows?

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install some modules using `pip`. My system is `Windows 7 64-bit`, and I'm using `Python Shell` and `Python 2.7`.

I've typed in following code to start the installation:

```
python -m pip install traitlets
```

According to [this page](https://docs.python.org/3.6/installing/index.html), the above code should work. However I've got `pip` highlighted in red and an error message:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone please point out what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 12):

You have to execute that command in a windows command prompt, not in a python shell.

Answer (score 10):

[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

This installed Pip at C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe. Find pip.exe on your computer, then add its folder (for example, C:\Python27\Scripts) to your path (Start / Edit environment variables). Now you should be able to run pip from the command line. Try installing a package:

pip install httpie